# GetRoomList() always returns empty array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I had been getting the room list in the `OnReceivedRoomListUpdate` function just fine, but recently, the `PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList()` inside this function always returns an empty array.

Here's my code:

```
public class RefreshRooms : Photon.PunBehaviour {
   ...

   void Start () {
        PhotonNetwork.autoJoinLobby = true;
        ...
        Refresh();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // FYI: Here, PhotonNetwork.countOfPlayers gives the correct count of players currently in the lobby
    }
    ...
    public void Refresh()
    {
        ...
        PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings("v3");
    }
    void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        // Display 'Fetching Rooms List...' message
        ...
    }

    void OnReceivedRoomListUpdate()
    {
        // Here PhotonNetowrk.GetRoomList().Length always gives 0, even if there are rooms

        // Also, this function is getting called only once in the entire lifecycle

        // FYI: PhotonNetwork.insideLobby gives true here
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm using PUN `v1.51`. Is there any change in the API which I need to implement now?

Comment: What is the length of the array returned? Also, please post how you are using this function

Comment: @Programmer PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList().Length is 0, and moreover, the `OnReceivedRoomListUpdate()` function is always called once in the entire lifecycle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like something changed in the Photon update. Many people had this problem after updating Photon. You now need to enable `AutoJoinLobby` before calling this function.

```
PhotonNetwork.autoJoinLobby = true;
```

Comment: Yes, I saw some posts, so I put it in the `Start()` right away, but no luck

Comment: Try that in the `Awake` function. Let me know. Also you care calling `Refresh()` which disconnects...Why not comment that line too?

Comment: Did that, still no luck. Should I remove the `ConnectUsingSettings`?

Comment: Don't remove, just comment it out

Comment: I commented both the `ConnectUsingSettings()` and `Disconnect()` functions, and set the `PhotonNetwork.autoJoinLobby = true` in the `Awake()` function, but now, the client doesn't connect in the first place. Is it because I haven't updated my plugin (I'm still using `v1.51`)? I didn't update it because everything else, including joining game, RPCs, and even `PhotonNetwork.countOfPlayers` is working perfectly, and I don't want it to break after updating

Comment: I really don't know what's going on now. How about you uncomment everything I told you to comment, then call `Room.visible = false` followed by `PhotonNetowrk.JoinLobby()` before you call `PhotonNetowrk.GetRoomList()`.

Comment: I am so sorry for this, it was a really bad silly mistake by me. I was connecting using the wrong version name. Sorry for this, and thanks for your efforts